# entity framework mark as modified code first 5

Tags: entity-framework

Marking a property as modified should be done like this:

```
using (var context = new UnicornsContext())
{
    var unicorn = context.Unicorns.Find(1);
    var nameIsModified1 = context.Entry(unicorn).Property(u => u.Name).IsModified;

    // Use a string for the property name
    var nameIsModified2 = context.Entry(unicorn).Property("Name").IsModified;
}
```

code sample from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/30/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-5-working-with-property-values.aspx)

In my code `UnicornsContext extends DBContext`.

I don't have a `Entry` method for my context. whats's wrong?

Comment: Have you referenced the right assembly, and import the correct namespace?

Comment: you were right, I had a bad assembly

Comment: I'm having the same problem; which assembly is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @jmpcm: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578%28v=vs.103%29.aspx (EntityFramework.dll, System.Data.Entity)